# Several threads writing to same log file

Tags: c, multithreading, file, thread-safety, reentrancy

I have studied several sources/forum threads/stackoverflow questions, but still can not decide on the correct/best architecture for the software therefore asking for your advice. I will use some pseudocode below.

**Simple task - write to log file**

```
volatile FILE* logFP;
pthread_mutex_t logFileMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
volatile long logFileSize;

main()
{
    ...
    (log file is being open here in single thread)
    (ensure lock is unlocked)
    ...
    (another threads are started)
    ...
    (threads are terminated)
    (log file closed)
    (exit)
}

void logToFile(char* instr)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(logFileMutex);
    fwrite(logFP, "some text %s\n", instr);
    fflush(logFP);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(logFileMutex);
}
```

As far as I understand this function `logToFIle()` is thread-safe and reentrant, right?

**More complicated task - perform log rotation**

```
volatile bool enableAutoLogRotation;

void logToFile(char* instr)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(logFileMutex);
    // if log file is not open, remove lock and do nothing
    if(logFP == NULL) { pthread_mutex_unlock(logFileMutex); return; }
    if(enableAutoLogRotation && (logFileSize >= SOME_THRESHOLD))
    {
        enableAutoLogRotation = false;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(logFileMutex);
        performLogRotation();
        pthread_mutex_lock(logFileMutex);
        enableAutoLogRotation = true;
    }

    fwrite(logFP, "some text %s\n", instr);
    fflush(logFP);
    logFileSize = ftell(logFP);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(logFileMutex);
}
```

Explanation: after locking the mutex I check for log rotation enabled `enableAutoLogRotation`, this flag is reset when log rotation task is in progress. After checking this flag I enable the mutex to ensure if `logToFile` is called by another thread, it will be able to acquire lock and write its message to the log file. Within `performLogRotation()`, when there's a file I/O operation (closing, moving contents, opening for append/creating) I also lock the mutex, otherwise it is unlocked. Important to note that `performLogRotation()` may also call `logToFile()`, therefore I ensure that mutex lock is removed before calling `logToFile()`.

```
void performLogRotation()
{
int error;
    ...
    pthread_mutex_lock(logFileMutex);
    fclose(logFP);
    error = remove(logFileName);
    logFP = fopen(logFileName, "a");    // logFP will be NULL on error, logging will be disabled
    pthread_mutex_unlock(logFileMutex);
    if(error < 0) logToFile("remove error");
    ...
}
```

Does this plan look correct? Anything I miss? Any other better way?

Comment: Doing a flush for each added line seems very inefficient (although safer), especially on HDD with a very low number of IOPS. You could try to make the flush only periodically and/or in a buffered way and in critical situations (eg. exit of the program). AFAIK, the lock section using `pthread_mutex_lock` is not reentrant unless you use recursive mutexes, but why you want this function to be reentrant?

Comment: @JérômeRichard thanks. This logging function may be called by another thread while "this" thread is within it. As well as it can be called from `performLogRotation()` (see example).

Comment: Many issues can be mitigated/avoided by queueing all log requests and/or commands to one thread that then performs all log actions.

Comment: @MartinJames interesting idea. What would be the mechanism passing data (strings) to that thread? Do you have any implementation examples?

Comment: @Anonymous Google 'producer consumer queue'.  Design some struct to hold log data and some command enum.  When you want to write something, malloc one, load it up, queue its address to the thread.  In the thread, dequeue the struct instances and perform the command within.  When done, free the struct.

Comment: Such a design insulates the main app from disk/network latencies.  The other 'maintainance' activities, eg 'open a new log file', 'rotate log file' etc etc can easily be requested by queueing up a command to the thread, or the thread could perform actions for itself, eg a timed wait on its input queue could flush the output file if no log writes have been received for x ms.

Comment: @MartinJames make your comments an answer please.